# Changing value for one matrix is changing the value for another matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

This may be a silly question, but just newly self-learning Python for a project, I have tried to find out the reason for quite some time and have failed.

So, I am using `numpy`, and I am trying to manipulate some matrices. I have a matrix (it is a randomly generated symmetric matrix of 0s and 1s, but for the sake of example, let us say it is `x` which is

```
[[0,1,1,1], 
[1,0,1,1], 
[1,1,0,1],
[1,1,1,0]]
```

I want to create another matrix `y`, for which I run the following code:

```
y = x
for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        if i == j:
            y[i][j] = 0
        else:
            ind = x[i] + x[j]
            cf = 0
            tf = 0
            for k in ind:
                if k == 1:
                    tf += 1
                if k == 2:
                    cf += 1
                    tf += 1
            if tf != 0:
                y[i][j] = cf/tf
            else:
                y[i][j] = 0
```

To my understanding, in this entire block of code, I have done nothing to change any element of `x`, and only manipulated `y` using information from `x`.

But at the end, if I run `print(x)`, I get the null matrix in return. Why is this happening? I played with the code for some time and I think the problem starts only in the last 4 lines:

```
            if tf != 0:
                y[i][j] = cf/tf
            else:
                y[i][j] = 0
```

But even here I have no idea why is `x` getting changed when I am only setting different elements of `y` in the code!!

PS: I tried this both with `numpy` arrays as matrices and with ordinary matrices in Python with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables that refer to objects in Python store references. When you are doing `y = x` you are assigning y to the reference stored in x, but both ultimately point to the same object in memory.

If you want a unique copy of the data of a numpy object use:

```
y = numpy.copy(x)
```

... which will do an actual data copy (and be a low slower).